# Setting a picture by name with a wildcard in VBA

Tags: excel, image, vba, shapes

I am trying to import a picture from one workbook into another and edit it.  I can't figure out the right way to name it or define it once it's pasted in the new workbook.  There will only be one picture in WB1, so I want the loop to go until it finds a picture.

It will be named something like Picture 1, Picture 2, Picture 10, etc. so I think I should be able to define mapSHP by something like "Picture *" but I can't get that to work.

Obviously I've defined WB1, WB2, and pasteWS previously and defined mapSHP as a shape.

```
For Each s In WB1.Worksheets
    If s.Pictures.Count > 0 Then
        For Each pic In s.Shapes
            pic.Copy

            WB2.Activate
            pasteWS.Range("A1").Select
            pasteWS.Pictures.Paste

            Set mapSHP = pic
            GoTo gotPic:
        Next pic
    End If
Next s
gotPic:
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `mapSHP.name="Picture " & i.` You need to include a `i=i+1` inside your `for each pic` loop.

Comment: Didn't really take much effort XD

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, the problem is that there is no way to tell a picture from a chart from a form object in the `Shapes` collection (AFAIK).

However, since you stated that the Picture will always have a name like `Picture 1 ... Picture 2 ... Picture 10` you can use the Shape.Name property to find the 1 picture in the sheet.

Then when you copy it over you can use the same name to set the object to the `mapSHP` variable as the name should be the same when pasted over.

See the code below. I refactored a little to make it more efficient:

```
For Each s In WB1.Worksheets

    If s.Shapes.Count > 0 Then

        For Each pic In s.Shapes

            If Left(pic.Name, 3) = "Pic" Then

                Dim sName As String
                sName = pic.Name
                pic.Copy

                Exit For 'since we found the picture, exit

            End If

        Next pic

        WB2.Sheets(pasteW2.Name).Range("A1").Paste

        Set mapSHP = WB2.Sheets(pasteW2.Name).Shapes(sName)
        GoTo gotPic:

    End If

Next s
gotPic:
```

Comment: I did too at first @findwindow!

Comment: I think @findwindow's interpretation was correct.  Thanks for helping.